# Prevent resizing of windows

Tags: java, window, jna

I am trying to take periodical(repeatedly) screenshots of inactive or background application's window. I have got the window rectangle, but if the user changes window rectangle, then I am getting screenshot with black shades respective to the size changes. I can get a rectangle each and every time before taking screenshot, but it makes my code slower, so I want to prevent the user from resizing his window or Is there any event trigger when window re-size happens? I am using `Java` with `JNA`. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Preventing your users resizing their windows is going to annoy them.  Do you really want to do that?

Comment: Or Is there any window re-size event? I could choose among these two. One prevention, Second Event handling. :)

Comment: Does getting the rectangle really make your code slower compared to grabbing the pixels?  A little surprising... in any case I agree with @rossum.

Comment: @Rob I am doing this task repeatedly say at least 2 - 4 times per window in second. So, performance is considered. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing to record screencast of applications using SWT components.
There is 1 listener that could do the job :

```
public class ShellControlsListener implements ControlListener {
    @Override
    public void controlMoved(ControlEvent e) {
         // You will need to retrieve new coordinates
    }
@Override
    public void controlResized(ControlEvent e) {
         // Do you work here: retrieve new bounds
    }
}
```

I supposed that you could use that kind of listener with awt/swing.

Retrieving window coordinates and bounds is not a real issue at 2~4 FPS. I am able to record and encode at 25 FPS using the java.awt.Robot. (Retrieving window bounds is fast compared to Robot.createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle).

If you really need performances, you only have to retrieve bounds when your window is moved or resized; there is no need to set window not resizeable (If you do not want to use your screenshots for video making, because in this case all screenshots should have the same dimensions).

Comment: Could you help me how to record particular window at 25 FPS? and How did you prevent the other application windows from resizing? Because, I tried to get 25 screens per second but I couldn't do so?

Comment: Basically the application is made of 1 background thread which capture screenshots using awt Robot (capture every 1/framerate seconds). Then the picture is given to a video encoder (Xuggle for instance). The 3rd component is a ControlListener which detect application resizing; but since I didn't use JNA, I cannot record non-Java window. The only way to achieve 25 FPS it is encode & record video on the fly. For the moment I can only record one window, but it is good enough for my needs. But I face performances issues when the window is too large (I have to decrease framerate).

Comment: The above listener inside my code will detect the size changes of other windows. Am I right?

Answer (score 2):

You can call `frame.setResizable(false)` to disable resizing the window. You could also do this:

```
frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
    public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
        // Update rectangle
    }
}
```

(Assuming here that frame is a `java.awt.Frame` or a `javax.swing.JFrame`)

Comment: I can prevent or respond to my application window size changes, but I want to know other window or application size changes.

Comment: Depending on your OS there might be a JNA call you could make to listen for resizing of windows in other applications. But I would agree that requesting the current window rectangle ought to be fast compared to grabbing the pixels. How much of a slowdown do you observe when you request the rectangle every time?

Comment: Currently, I am repeatedly doing `JNA` call every time. Grabbing the pixels consumes times, but I can't omit it as the content inside the window keeps on changing. I am tuning code to perform better, so thought of removing this window rectangle `JNA` call, which would be worthless if user is not re-sizing the window.